# how to code a function in matlab which will display pixels of an gray image which is not repeated

Tags: matlab

hi i m trying to implement huffman code which has following steps:

Development of Huffman Coding and Decoding  Algorithm

Step1-  Read the image on to the workspace of the mat 
lab.
Step2-  Convert the given colour image into grey level 
image.

Step3-  Call a function which will find the symbols  (i.e. 
pixel value which is non-repeated).

Step4-  Call a function which will calculate the 
probability of each symbol.

Step5-  Probability of symbols are arranged in decreasing 
order and lower probabilities are merged and this
step is continued until only two probabilities are 
left and codes are assigned according to rule that 
:the highest probable symbol will have a shorter 
length code.

Step6-  Further Huffman encoding is performed i.e. 
mapping of the code words to the corresponding 
symbols will result in a compressed data.

Step7-  The original image is reconstructed i.e. 
decompression is done  by using Huffman 
decoding.

Step8-  Generate a tree equivalent to the encoding tree.

Step9- Read input character wise and left to the table II 
until last element is reached in the table II.

Step10 -Output the character encode in the leaf and return 
to the root, and continue the step9 until all the 
codes of corresponding symbols are known.

i have implemented steps 1 & 2..in 3rd steps i m able to display the pixels of an image using function impixelregion; but i m not able to find how to code a function which will display pixels values which are not repeated..kindly help me plzzz...

Answer (score 0):

See [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) i.e. use imhist(I,256), where I is your gray image.